# Как вывести сообщение об ошибке или успехе?

Tags: php

Сейчас у меня вот такой код, но я не могу сформулировать, чем он меня не устраивает и что вообще я хочу получить. Может быть тут как-то можно использовать тернарный оператор?

Судя по заголовку, я хочу получить вывод сообщения об ошибке при выполнении условия `isset($err)` и сообщение об успехе при выполнении условия `isset($succ)`.

```
<?php if(isset($err)) { ?>
        <div class=""><?= $err; ?></div>
    <?php } elseif(isset($succ)) {?>
        <div class=""><?= $succ; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: ПРИ ЧЕМ ЗДЕСЬ "тернарный оператор" вообще?

Comment: Если сообщения не отличаются друг от друга, то и не нужно их разделять, а использовать только одну переменную.

Comment: Перед тем как редактировать вопрос, следует сопоставить его с тем ответом, который автор вопроса пометил решением. Увеличивать количество шизофрении на этом сайте не требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
if(isset($error))
    echo '<div class="error">'.$error.'</div>';
elseif(isset($success))
    echo '<div class="success">'.$success.'</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
isset($err) ? $err : isset($succ) ? isset($succ) : $somethingElse
```

Comment: скобки только ставьте в таких выражениях

Comment: в целом эта запись равносильна `$err ?: $succ ?: $somethingElse` только вот автор просил без `$somethgineElse`

Comment: Кто поставил плюс этому ответу? В мануале черным по белому написано, [**Рекомендовано избегать «нагромождения» тернарных выражений.**](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php). Плюс очевидно, что автору **вообще не нужен никакой тернарный оператор**, он просто не может толком описать свои проблемы.

Comment: @Ипатьев, ну я плюсанул. как и флаганул. и? будете теперь меня люто ненавидеть? :3 p.s. `рекомендация !== запрет` всегда были есть и будут ситуации требующие отойти от рекомендаций. более того рекомендация нацелена на поддержание читабельности кода, а не на то что бы бездумно ненавидеть тернарник, который к слову в умелых руках не только ни капли не портит читабельности, но порой и поддерживает её получше многих прочих инструментов. так что...)))

Comment: @Ипатьев, историю правок вопросов и ответов никто не отменял. видно что вопрос не исходный *мягко говоря...* :3

Comment: @Ипатьев я правильно понимаю, что вы пишете исключительно идеальный код и никогда не отходите от best practice? Именно, чёрным по белому написано "Рекомендовано". Вложенные тернарные операторы неудобны для чтения и работы, но это не ошибка. Я использую их, когда мне просто так проще, а такие ситуации бывают, но редко. Человек задал вопрос, я ответил. Согласен, что автору не нужен тернарный оператор, но исходя из моего ответа, он мог это понять и использовать классический if else

Comment: При чем здесь то что пишу лично я? Здесь публичный сервис качественных ответов на вопросы, а не сервис по распространению говнокода. Не можете написать качественный ответ - не надо писать вовсе

Comment: @Ипатьев Ну и я могу в вашем ключе отвечать) - То ли дело ваш ответ, который полон полезности. Не умеете адекватно комментировать и давать верные ответы с пояснениями - идите к психологу и прорабатывайте свои личные травмы и проблемы со вниманием и самооценкой

Answer (score 0):

Тернарный оператор, даже если каким-то способом его тут получится применить, вряд ли сделает этот код более читаемым. Я бы остановился на примерно таком варианте

```
<?php if ($err || $succ): ?>
   <div class=""><?= $err ?? $succ ?></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

или как вариация

```
<?php
if ($msg = $err ?? $succ) {
    echo "<div class=''>{$msg}</div>";
}
```